# Reading NFC data in real time

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, scanning

I have an NFC tag and whenever I try to read it using my phone, it shows stuff like "Transceive failed" or "Unable to read". When it does read it, it shows little to no information about the tag.

However when my NFC tag communicates with one particular NFC reader, it performs a certain action. So there must be some kind of private data hidden inside of it that I can't read by myself.

Now I was wondering what I could do to read read those informations and maybe see something that I can't see using a regular NFC reader. Maybe by reading the data being transferred to that particular  NFC reader in real time ?

Here's some informations about the tag :

```
Technology : 
[IsoDep,NfcB,]
android.nfc.tech.IsoDep
android.nfc.tech.NfcB

Provides access to NFC-B 
ISO 14443-3(Type B) properties 

Maximum Transceive Length : 
65279 bytes
Maximum Transceive Time-out : 
618 ms
```

Thanks.